# Trying to call a webservice in my app but is is not found

Tags: javascript, web-services

I am trying to call a webservice. The webservice and calling code are all in the same project.  When the javascript function tries to call the webservice  function AttnCcc.saveAttnCcc, I get error : Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'AttnCcc' is undefined

The following code is in the aspx file which calls the service:

```
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
  <Services>
  <asp:ServiceReference Path="AttnCcc.asmx.cs" /> 
  </Services>    
  </asp:ScriptManager>
```

In the same aspx file, I am trying to call it from the following js function:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function ConfirmCcc(ID, webDataGridName) {
           AttnCcc.saveAttnCcc("44,duplicate,this test data");
       }
</script>
```

THe webservice is the the following asmx.cs file:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace  are
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for AttnCcc
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class AttnCcc : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [ScriptMethod]
        [WebMethod]
        public void saveAttnCcc(string ccc)
        {
            string cblCccText, tbCccText;
            int Id;
            string[] arr = ccc.Split(',');
            Id = int.Parse(arr[0]);
            cblCccText = arr[1]; tbCccText = arr[2];
        }

    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may want to look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/WebServiceCallApp.aspx?display=Print, but I expect the id of the html element in the page source, within the browser, is different, so just do "View Page Source" and verify that the id is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call a webservice of type void.

I changed to to return an int I never use and the calling js was able to find it.

```
 public int saveAttnCcc(string ccc) {
... 
return dummyInt;
}
```